# Awk script not catching hash symbol "#"

Tags: awk, regular-expression

How can I get awk to ignore records begining with a comment while keeping all other records? The below awk script does not ignore the records beginning with a hash symbol in this sample test file. It also skips `numpy` record.

Test file

```c
# Version numbers have been retrieved from a range of machines and environments.
# Take them with a grain of salt.

# Direct dependencies
#python==3.6.0
#pip==9.0.1
#setuptools==38.2.4  # old for MarkupSafe 1.0 (28.8.0 is installed with py 3.6)
numpy==1.12.1  # 1.12.0
pandas==0.19.2
```

Awk script

```c
#! /usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { 
  regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+\S+/ 
  n=0
}

$1 ~ regex {print $1; n++};

END{
  {print "\n# \n# End proccessing of "FILENAME" \n# Original file had "NR" records\n# Current file record count is "n};
  { if(NR>=n) print "#\n# Mattached all records"};
}
```

Output (ignore bars)

```c
|| #python==3.6.0
|| #pip==9.0.1
|| pandas==0.19.2
|| 
|| # 
|| # End proccessing of requirements.txt 
|| # Original file had 9 records
|| # Current file record count is 3
|| #
|| # Mattached all records
```

Comment: awk version `20070501`

Comment: `grep -v '^#'  testfile`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+\S+/` means "compare `$0` to `/^[a-zA-Z]+\S+/` and save the result in the variable `regex`" so `regex` will be 1 or 0 as a result of that assignment and since we're in the `BEGIN` section where no lines have been read and so $0 is still empty, it's equivalent to `regex=0`.

`\S` is a GNU awk extension which means `[^[:space:]]` so if you were using GNU awk - it also supports strongly typed regexp constants (see https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Strong-Regexp-Constants). With that in mind you could do (note the `@` symbol):

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN{re=@/3/} $0 ~ re'
3
```

but only in GNU awk.

In any other awk variant (which given you say you're using version `20070501` I suspect you are using a BSD variant) the best you can do is use a dynamic regexp:

```
$ seq 5 | awk 'BEGIN{re="3"} $0 ~ re'
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of the errors. I wish could up-vote both this and @ThomasDickey answer. With so many different variants of regex used by different tools (vim, awk, git, grep, ect...) it can be a pain trying to remember their differences. Need a translator of some sort.

Comment: @tkolleh you _can_ in fact upvote both. You just can't accept both.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an awk pattern (looks like perl):

```
regex=/^[a-zA-Z]+\S+/
```

something like this would work:

```
regex="^[a-zA-Z]+[^[:space:]]+"
```

Also, your pattern should match against `$0` (not `$1`).  `$0` is the whole line.  `$1` is the first field (think of it as the first **word** on each line: that may not have a **`#`** to match against in the first column).

With those two corrections, your example works for me...

Comment: Works great with awk (BSD).

Comment: $0 is the whole line. But $1 is the first field, not the second.

Comment: agreed (long day...)